Was Sanjaya able to hear the Bhagavad Gita and was he able to see the Vishwarupa of Krishna that Arjuna saw?
did the Divya-drishti Sanjaya was given to be able to relate the war to Dhritarashtra include hearing the Gita and viewing the Vishwarupa of Krishna Arjuna saw?

Yes. Sanjaya explicitly says that.

Sanjaya said, “I have thus heard this wonderful and thrilling
dialogue between the great souls Vasudeva and Partha. Through the
blessings of Vyasa, I have heard this supreme and secret yoga directly
from Krishna, the lord of all yoga, when he stated it. O king!
Remembering again and again this sacred and wonderful dialogue between
Keshava and Arjuna, I have repeatedly been exhilarated. O king!
Remembering that extremely wonderful universal form of Hari, I am greatly amazed and repeatedly exhilarated. Wherever  there is
Krishna, the lord of yoga, and Arjuna, the wielder of the bow, exist
prosperity, victory, increase in wealth and sound policy. That is my
conviction.


900 (40), Bhagavad Gita parva, Mahabharata.

